# Dividing values in each cell by the group average in R

Tags: r, charts, dplyr

I am trying to generate a new column with values derived from the original chart. I would like to calculate the group average of same hotel and same date first, then use this group averages to divide the original sales.

Here is my code: I tried to calculate the group average by using group_by and summarise embedding in dplyr package, however, it did not generate my [expected results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WA1er.jpg).

```
hotel = c(rep("Hilton",3), rep("Caesar",3))
date1 = c(rep('2018-01-01',2), '2018-01-02', rep('2018-01-01',3))
dba = c(2,0,1,3,2,1)
sales = c(3,5,7,5,2,3)
df = data.frame(cbind(hotel, date1, dba, sales))

df1 = df %>%
  group_by(date1, hotel) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(avg = mean(sales)) %>%
  acast(., date1~hotel)
```

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of summarise, we can use `mutate`.  After grouping by 'date1', 'hotel', divide the 'sales' by the `mean` of 'sales' to create a new column

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   group_by(date1, hotel) %>% 
   mutate(SalesDividedByMean = sales/mean(sales))
```

NOTE: When there are columns having different `type`s, `cbind`ing results in a `matrix` and `matrix` can have only a single type.  So, a `character` class vector can change the whole data into `character`.  Wrapping with `data.frame`, propagate that change into either `factor` (by default `stringsAsFactors = TRUE` or `character)

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(hotel, date1, dba, sales)
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Thanks a lot! But there is a little bit confusion: the "mean(sales)" here I got is the overall average, instead of the average within same date and hotel. Is there anything I misunderstood?

Comment: Oh never mind. I library package plyr after dplyr, which makes my group_by work weird. Thanks for the help!